# getApplication() returns null in service which was killed

Tags: android, android-service

I kill service I made in my application, and when it is being restarted with  `START_REDELIVER_INTENT` flag `getApplication()` methods returns `null`. 
I call it like so ( Service class )

```
@Override
public void onCreate(){
    this.wifiApp = (WifiApplication) getApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with methods I called in the arrived WifiApplication instance, which wasn't null